# ASP.net Limit user functions based on custom table roles and permissions, not ASP Memberships

Tags: asp.net, sql, authentication

I have an ASP.net website, with MS SQL Server on the backend.

For simplicity, I will describe my problem with three four tables though in reality it is much more than that.

TABLES:

tblSYSTEMS
•   SystemID (PK)
•   SystemDescription
•   Other columns

tblSYSTEMS_Projects (many projects can be associated with each SYSTEM)
•  Various fields that users can see/modify/delete, based on permissions.

USERS (as generated by ASP.net, for user/membership/roles etc...)
•   userid
•   Other columns

tblSYSTEMS_PERMISSIONS_LINK (this links the two tables)
•   SystemID
•   userid
•   AllowEdit
•   AllowView
•   AllowDelete
•   AllowInsert

I set up a Stored Procedure for each of the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE functions in the database for tblSYSTEMS_Projects.

When the user goes to change/add/delete a record in tblSYSTEMS_Projects, I send a parameter of @userid (from the currently logged in user) to the SP.

For UPDATE I check to see that in tblSYSTEMS_PERMISSIONS_LINK they have AllowEdit set as true, for a given SYSTEM in tblSYSTEMS.  The way the tables are linked, if they don't have EDIT permissions, there won't be a row updated (becuase the WHERE clause essentially returns 0 rows), which I get back in my execution of the SP.  Fine.

Same goes for DELETE.

But for INSERT, there are no WHERE clauses available for INSERTING records into tblSYSTEMS_Projects.

1. How can I prevent a userid who does not have INSERT priveledges for a particular SYSTEM from inserting into the tblSYSTEMS_Projects table?
2. When the currently logged in userid tries to click on INSERT, what can I do to redirect them to a "you do not have epermission" page?
3. Can I simply hide the INSERT command based on currently logged in userid?  When would I do that?  On Page load?  Any suggestions on methodology to do that?  Simple SP that returns a scalar of the INSERT value?

I looked at roles/memberships etc... but that doesn't quite work, as many different people have different permissions based on the SYSTEM.  In one system, one person could be an ADMIN, and ini another system, be a viewer only.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have users only have access to their records, but only granting them permission to do what they are allowed to do.  But those permissions vary based on SystemID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of way to do it. Here is my approach which is **Role based authorization** -

I'll restrict authorization based on user's roles. For example, if **System** is in **AddRole** and a user is in **AddRole**, then the user can create a new record.

Page's authorization logic should not in Store Procedure alone. Instead, it should be started in Presentation Layer (such as Controller).

If you need addition logic checking, you can place it Business Logic layer.

[image]

```
tblSYSTEMS_PERMISSIONS_LINK (this links the two tables)
• SystemID
• userid
• AllowEdit
• AllowView 
• AllowDelete
• AllowInsert
```

You should not create about **tblSYSTEMS_PERMISSIONS_LINK** table with individual column. *It is not a good database design, unless you can 100% ensure that there won't be any new **Authorization Type** in the future.*

Comment: I think I see what you are doing.  There also needs to be a Field inside UsersInRoles that is part of the primary key that links the System.  As I stated, a user can have Edit privileges in system A but only view in System B.  So the role is user/system dependent.  I like the idea of adding a role table, too.

Comment: If you use **DefaultRole** provider, you cannot add any additional columns to **UsersInRoles** table. in other words, if you add a column to **UsersInRoles**, you'll have to create **Custom Role Provider**.

Comment: As of now, I am only using the ASP.net provided tables to control the logins.  I only care about ASP.net managing the users, not necessarily the roles.  I only am using this to get the userid of the currently logged in user.

Comment: It is catch 22. By and large, if you need **authentication** in your application, you want to use **Role Based Authentication**. In order to use Role Based Authentication, you need **Roles** table.